# I am creating a new thread in foreach loop on every how I can show progress of each thread in listview c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, listview, foreach, progress-bar

This is the code:

```
 foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
            {
                listViewItems = listView1.Items.Count;
                string path = Properties.Settings.Default.outputFolder;
                IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videos = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(item.Text);
                VideoInfo video = videos.First(p => p.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4);
                if (video.RequiresDecryption)
                    DownloadUrlResolver.DecryptDownloadUrl(video);
                title = video.Title;
                foreach (char c in invalid)
                {
                    title = title.Replace(c.ToString(), "");
                }
                VideoDownloader downloader = new VideoDownloader(video, Path.Combine(path + "\\", title + video.VideoExtension));
                downloader.DownloadProgressChanged += Downloader_DownloadProgressChanged;
                downloader.DownloadFinished += Downloader_DownloadFinished;
                Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    downloader.Execute();
                })
                { IsBackground = true };

                thread.Start();
            }
```

and this is the ProgressChanged event:

```
    private void Downloader_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        overallprogressbar.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
        {
            overallprogressbar.Value = (int)e.ProgressPercentage;
        }));
    }
```

Only progressbar named as overallprogressbar showing the progress of all items. What I want is to show progress of each thread and if possible then in third coulmn of listview. 
I am creating a YouTube downloader and i want to show progress of each download in listview as most of the downloaders have if not as a progressbar but only as a numbers like 0.0% will do good.

Comment: "Only progressbar named as overallprogressbar showing the progress of all items" - but it's the element you change (overallprogressbar.Value =...)

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev i am using a progressbar to show progress because i have no idea how i can create multiple progressbar with respect to the numbers of items in listview.